# What is the difference between 'either by' and 'by either'

Tags: difference

what is the difference?

- *I've not been defeated by either A or B.*
- *I've not been defeated either by A or B.*

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference in meaning: it's just a matter of scope.

Formally, in careful speaking or writing, people will say either

*by either A or B*

where the "either" is inside the scope of the "by"; or else

*either by A or by B*

where the "either" is not in the scope of the "by", and you need to repeat "by", to maintain the parallellism.

In practice, in ordinary speech, many people will say *either by A or B*, and neither they nor most of their hearers will notice anything odd.